# Is it possible to swap option and command keys for a specific keyboard?

Tags: mac, keyboard, macos, keybindings

I just bought a Logitech USB keyboard (Logitech K120, if that matters.) It's a Windows keyboard, so it has a Windows key and an alt key. The Windows key maps to Command, and the Alt key maps to option. The keys are reversed from their positions on a normal Mac keyboard. It's driving me nuts.

I'm running 10.12.1 (Sierra)

Is there any way to remap them, for this specific keyboard?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can change the functions of the modifier keys (Caps Lock, Control, Option, Command) in System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Modifier Keys.

If you have more than one keyboard, the setting window allows you to select and set separate mapping for each one:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't seem to apply to Mojave with a bluetooth keyboard. Any ideas?

Comment: This worked for me as I had the same issue as @Sinjai https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/342863/358510

Comment: Yup, I ended up using Karabiner Elements too. Works great, though multi-key changes can be a pain. The good news is there is a marketplace of sorts where you can download those. It's been a lifesaver.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it switches the keys on the BT keyboard as well as on the laptop, so that when you go mobile the keys are incorrectly switched. If you always use the BT keyboard this may be fine, but if you mix between that and the laptop keyboard then it will be frustrating. The next answer below about switching modes on the Logitech keyboards works better for the mixed mode.

Answer (score 16):

Note that some Logitech keyboards, like the K850 or Craft, allow swapping mode via pressing and holding for 2-3 seconds.

- <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> for mac layout
- <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> for pc layout

Source: https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/B1dTBxzD3hS.pdf

Comment: Work on Ergo K860! Tip: it's a LONG PRESS, you have to hold the combination for 2-3 seconds.

Comment: I can confirm that this works on Logitech Craft. For some reason, the layout switched to PC layout after upgrading to macOS Moneterey.

Answer (score 6):

Although the accepted answer should have worked, but in my case it didn't. I have the same Logitech USB Keyboard.

What worked for me?

1. I Installed [Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/)
2. Then i swaped the keys.

[image]

And within a second, everything was back to normal :) Hope it helps.

Answer (score -4):

Have you looked into using a keyboard remapping program such as [Sharp Keys](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com)?

Comment: No, I'm not familiar with those. That will do what I need?

Comment: Most likely @DuncanC try it out and see where it takes you.

Comment: That's a Windows app. How should it work in OS X/macOS?

Comment: Sharp Keys is a windows utility. Are there similar programs for Mac OS?

Comment: Karabiner is a similar app for OSX

Comment: Why pile on down-votes for this answer just because he gave an example app for Windows? It's a good suggestion. Maybe he should have said "a Mac equivalent of the Windows program 'Sharp Keys', but let's not hate on a Windows user for offering useful suggestions!