# how do I switch option + f to [next word] instead of ƒ

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

on macos high Sierra I want to switch option + f to [next word] instead of ƒ. How do I do that?

For example in the [bear text editing app](https://bear.app/), I’d love this affordance.

How can I change the key mappings or make this a shortcut on macOS?

Or for example I would like to delete a word with option + d, instead it prints out the useless ∂

Comment: One can skip words with option +left, right arrows and delete words with option delete. Wouldn't that be helpful ?

Comment: big wast of time, i could use the mouse instead then as well.

Answer (score 1):

All those shortcuts you mention work with <kbd>control</kbd>+_. So either you can remap your option key to behave as control, or make yourself habitual of using <kbd>control</kbd>.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236

- [Swap CMD and Alt only on external keyboard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/225089/swap-cmd-and-alt-only-on-external-keyboard/225127#225127)
- [How do I remap a key in macOS Sierra, e.g., Right Alt to Right Control?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/283252/how-do-i-remap-a-key-in-macos-sierra-e-g-right-alt-to-right-control)

Comment: Control + f is moving forward one letter, but not one word!

Comment: Oh thanks for pointing out, as I said above, option can be used

Comment: but option + f writes ƒ and is not moving forward. please help me understand

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378576/how-do-i-switch-option-f-to-next-word-instead-of-ƒ/378741?noredirect=1#comment511344_378576 Use the shortcuts defined in https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236 and make them your habit.  :)